# Windows 7 : Stop showing tooltip when hovering oppened applications on taskbar and instantly show thumbnails preview

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, taskbar

I'm having a hard time figuring out somethihng on windows 7. I would like to disable the useless tooltip from showing on my taskbar application icons once i hover my mouse on them and instead i would like to instantly show thumbnail previews.

I have set the registery key for MouseHoverDelay to 0 (for instant thumbnail) already but it only shows the thumbnail preview instantly after showing the useless tooltip popup. My guess is that the tooltip is blocking the thumbnail preview from showing up as fast as i want. Also the tooltip takes about 2 seconds to show up and that's pretty frustrating.

Either disable the tooltip from the taskbar or the tooltip not preventing the thumbnails preview would be perfect.

Many thanks.

EDIT : Been a while now. Anybody knows any clue?

Comment: Are you using Aero (or what the new interface on Windows is called) or Windows Classic theme?

Comment: Aero. The thumbnails work but they are being blocked by the tooltip box comming beforehand.